# Why does /true|false/ match true/false, not truealse/trufalse?

Tags: regex

I accidentally left the parentheses out of

```regex
/true|false/
```

but it worked! As far as I know, a `|` means "the preceding pattern or the succeeding pattern", so `e` or `f`, or the equivalent of `/tru(e|f)alse/`. I noticed my error afterwards but was perplexed. Shouldn't this only match `truealse` and `trufalse`? Then I did more tests and found it matches those, *too*! **Why would this match `true`, `false`, `truealse`, and `trufalse`?**

Fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/90CEll/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "preceding pattern" is *everything preceding the `|`*, within the current group. So, `true` is the preceding pattern, and `false` is the succeeding pattern.

If you had actually wanted to match only `trufalse` and `truealse`, you'd use `tru(e|f)alse` to establish a grouping around the `|`.

As for why it matches `truealse`: it's matching `true` since you didn't specify any anchors. Therefore, it will match any string that has `true` or `false` in it.

Comment: To add to this: the capturing group in `tru(e|f)alse` will capture `e` or `f`, depending on the input string. If you only want to perform grouping, but not capturing, you can use a non-capturing group instead: `tru(?:e|f)alse`.

Comment: @AmalMurali: capturing/non-capturing groups are somewhat dialect-dependent. Since OP didn't specify a dialect, I didn't want to explain it. (Thanks for your clarification, though!)